# How a Spring WebApp manages different clients' request?

Tags: spring, validation, web-applications, jaxb, spring-ws

probably there are a lot of people who will smile reading this question...

Here's my problem.
I have a Spring 3 web application acting both as a client and server. It gets some XML data from a client "C", it processes them, and it sends them to a server "S".
The input XML fron C must be validated against a schema (e.g. "c.xsd") while the output XML to S must be validated against a different one (e.g. "s.xsd").

I'm using jaxb2 for marshalling and unmarshalling.

In the documentation I read that it is possible to set the "schema" attribute for the [un]/marshaller.

Therefore, I need to have an a.xsd for the validation when I get an input and a b.xsd when I produce an output... the question is the following:
when I switch the validation schema from c,xsd to s.xsd (producing an output after processing a request from C), do I change the status of the server? In other words, If I am receiving a second request form a client C2 when I'm processing the first request from C, will I attempt to validate C2 input against s.xsd? Will the application automatically put the C2 request on a different thread? If not, how can I configure spring to do so?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at it:

> The input XML fron C must be validated
>   against a schema (e.g. "c.xsd")

You can do this by setting a schema (c.xsd) on the Unmarshaller.

> while the output XML to S must be
>   validated against a different one
>   (e.g. "s.xsd").

You can do this by setting a schema (s.xsd) on the Marshaller.

> when I switch the validation schema
>   from c,xsd to s.xsd (producing an
>   output after processing a request from
>   C), do I change the status of the
>   server?

No, because the Unmarshaller is always using c.xsd and the Marshaller is always using s.xsd.

Since Marshaller and Unmarshaller are not thread safe you must be sure not to share them among threads.

Comment: ok, I get it. Since I have to respond to the client C I need a marshaller using c.xsd, but it doesn't change the things very much. I still need two different instances of the jaxb bean and the problem is solved. Switching to the thread mangement issue, from your post I understand the following: the server manages every request in a new thread but I must be carefull to set the shared resources as thread safe, right? If I don't behave in this way, I will use a stateful server, managing clients' requests in different ways.